# Parsing a string in clock format into int

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm new at learning Android, and working on a simple timer program. As of now, I have the code set up to create the timer from a passed in int. The design has a start button that will start the timer and refresh the TextView every second with the new time.

Right now, I'm working on pausing and restarting the timer. My idea is canceling the CountDownTimer when the user clicks pause and getting the new value for a new CountDownTimer from the TextView  that is displaying the time when the user paused (Display as 00:00).

How do I parse the string from the TextView, getting the separate numbers for minutes and seconds?

Comment: If you have access to the timer, why would you want to retrieve the information from the `TextView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Good you can separate string and get as a minute and second
Use This

```
String minute=textView1.getText().split(":")[0];
    String second=textView1.getText().split(":")[1];
```

You can convert String in Int using

```
int min=Integer.parseInt(minute);
```

or use

```
int min=Integer.ValueOf(minute);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I had to alter it a little bit, using toString() instead, but otherwise, a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
Timer t=new Timer();

        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Date d = new Date();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.setText(d.getMinutes() +":" + d.getSeconds());
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0,1000);
```

Comment: Where is this `runOnUiThread` method coming from? I think you meant that you want that piece of code to be ran on an EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) in which case you should use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable);`

Comment: runOnUiThread is a method of an Activity class . to use this method you must be in Activity class.